# Comparing dictionary values to a list of input string criteria

Tags: python, dictionary, eval

I am trying to write a Python script that accepts a string list of criteria, compares it to values in a dictionary, and executes if the criteria are met (or it throws an error message).

An example criteria list and dictionary values are given below:

```
criteria_list = ['A < 5', 'B == 6', '3 < C < 4']
dict = {'A': 3, 'B': 6, 'C': 3.5, 'D': 5, 'E': 100}
```

My initial thought was to have load in the values of the dictionary that are relevant to the criteria by checking if the criteria values are in the dictionary. I could then check if the value satisfies the criteria and then execute the code. If the criteria value is not in the dictionary then throw an error (i.e. criteria_list = [..., "Z == 10", ...] > throws an error that Z is not in the dictionary).

This is what I have now, but I'm having trouble finding a way to save the key value locally to use the eval(criteria) to check if the criteria is True or False.

```
crit_sum = 0
     
for criteria in criteria_list:        
   for key in dict.keys():       
      if (key in criteria.split()):
                 
         #SAVE KEY VALUE (i.e. A = 3)
                 
         if eval(criteria):
            crit_sum += 1
        
         elif (key not in critera.split()):
            print("criteria not in dictionary!")
    
if crit_sum == len(criteria_list):  #execute code if all criteria are TRUE                
   #EXECUTE CODE
```

Let me know what you think a good way of saving values locally or another way that could work for evaluating an arbitrary sized criteria list.

Comment: Hi mojojojo, I actually created a pypi package that does this called [ifcollector](https://github.com/jgrugru/ifcollector). You can install it with `pip3 install ifcollector`. If you're wanting to accept an arbitrary amount of criteria, pass the criteria to a function and accept *args. That way you can accept as many criteria as you need.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're aware of [why *not* to use `eval()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1832957/843953). However, if you still wish to do so, you can pass an empty dict to the `globals` argument and your dict to the `locals` argument of `eval()`. For example:

```
criteria_list = ['A < 5', 'B == 6', '3 < C < 4']
all_vars = {'A': 3, 'B': 6, 'C': 3.5, 'D': 5, 'E': 100}

crit_sum = 0
for crit in criteria_list:
    if eval(crit, {}, all_vars): 
        crit_sum += 1

if crit_sum == len(criteria_list):
    print("Success!")
```

Or, as using a generator expression:

```
criteria_list = ['A < 5', 'B == 6', '3 < C < 4']
all_vars = {'A': 3, 'B': 6, 'C': 3.5, 'D': 5, 'E': 100}

if sum(eval(crit, {}, all_vars) for crit in criteria_list) == len(criteria_list):
    print("Success!")
```

When an expression uses a variable that doesn't exist in `all_vars` (e.g. `X == 100`), you get a `NameError: name 'X' is not defined` that can be caught and handled if you prefer.

Comment: Is there a better way that doesn't include eval() that you recommend? I see in the link they have a set attribute function but I'm not using classes. I'm dealing with 20+ keys in the dictionary and want the flexibility to make the criteria list as large or small as I need to be.

Answer (score 0):

```
criteria_list = ['A < 5', 'B == 6', '3 < C < 4']
dic = {'A': 3, 'B': 6, 'C': 3.5, 'D': 5, 'E': 100}
crit_sum = 0
for k,v in dic.items():
    for i in criteria_list:
        if k in i:
            if eval(i.replace(k,str(v))):
                crit_sum+=1
        else:
            print("criteria not in dictionary!")
print(crit_sum)
if crit_sum == len(criteria_list):    #execute code if all criteria are TRUE 
    #EXECUTE CODE
```